# Finding the type of a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to do something like this:

```
SomeType *y;

/* ... snip ... */

auto x = new decltype(y); // Create a new pointer "x" to a SomeType object.
```

But `decltype(y)` is `SomeType*` and `decltype(*y)` is `SomeType&`. Is there a way to get plain `SomeType` out of `y`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `decltype(*y)` is a reference, you can use [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference):

```
new std::remove_reference<decltype(*y)>::type;
```

Comment: I ended up going with `new std::remove_pointer<decltype(y)>::type;` but this works fine too.